# Set value of input field

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I am trying to set the value of some text box and lists using javascript. The page will update with the values accordingly but when I submit the page it acts as if the values haven't been set.

I am setting the values in the console of the browser using javascript like this `document.getElementById("mytext").value = "My value";` which the page then updates the view and then does not save as mentioned.

I am not sure if maybe I am going about this wrong or it's not possible with the software being used. The interface is an IBM BPM Coach View/Salient Process Spark UI.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: @Barmar when I do it with a text box it and submit it tells me to ensure I've filled in all of the required areas and then highlights the one I used the JavaScript to fill.  I also tried with the listbox and the first item will select but then the sub menu items will not be in the tier two list (as if it didn't realize I selected something for the tier 1 box and was still empty as well)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the framework is using hidden inputs or JavaScript variables that it updates as you edit the form, and assigning to the value doesn't trigger this update. You'll need to check the documentation of the software to find out how to tell it that you've updated the value so it gets in sync.